# Start ERROR: E is not a recognized option

Tags: cratedb

Crate Version : 2.1.5
OS : Windows

I have an error when starting whith crate.bat:

```
PS D:\Dev\Crate\crate-2.1.5\bin> .\crate.bat
starts CrateDB

Option          Description
-C <KeyValuePair>     Configure a setting
-V, --version         Prints CrateDB version information and exits
-d, --daemonize       Starts CrateDB in the background
-h, --help            show help
-p, --pidfile <Path>  Creates a pid file in the specified path on start
-q, --quiet           Turns off standard ouput/error streams logging in console
-s, --silent          show minimal output
-v, --verbose         show verbose output
**ERROR: E is not a recognized option**
```

> Java path is : "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java"  -Xms256m
>   -Xmx1g -Xss256k -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djna.nosys=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0  -cp "D:\Dev\Crate\crate-2.1.5/lib/*;D:\Dev\Crate\crate-2.1.5/lib/enterprise/*;D:\Dev\Crate\crate-2.1.5/lib/sigar/*"
>   "io.crate.bootstrap.CrateDB" -Epath.home="D:\Dev\Crate\crate-2.1.5" -V

Do you have the same problem?

An idea of ​​where the error might come from?

Thanks

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the upcoming release of 2.1 - Thanks. https://github.com/crate/crate/issues/6129

Answer (score 0):

Work around in the meantime:

In crate.bat, replace

```
set CRATE_PARAMS=-Epath.home="%CRATE_HOME%"
```

by

```
set CRATE_PARAMS=-Cpath.home="%CRATE_HOME%"
```

and remove:

```
    ) else if "!param:~0,2!" equ "-C" (
        set param=!param:-C=-E!
```

source: https://github.com/crate/crate/pull/6142